# Concurrent commitment to 2 Masters degrees, One of them is online

Tags: graduate-admissions, online-degree

I am more likely to get admitted to 2 programs in 2 different universities. Both are great but in 2 different interests for me. The first is a non-thesis based program and mostly online while the second is a thesis-based research master degree.

**My question:** Assuming I can do well with both, are there any legal issues or concerns?

Given that I don't have to take the classes in person in one program, should I tell any of them?

what is your feedback if this scenario is in Canada and/or the USA?

Comment: Are either of the programs funded?

Comment: Both can be funded through the same governmental scholarship which is a part of the application but, for sure, I have to choose one of them to have this fund.
The research master program, however, is guaranteed to be funded through the school of graduate studies although they encourage applicants to apply for external scholarships.
Let's say that the main program is the thesis-based research program which is eligible for being funded through the university and governmental scholarships. If I can pay the ruin fees for the other non-thesis online Master degree, is there any issue?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the intricate details of how you are provided funding, you might be prohibited from taking the second Masters program. They usually have a good reason for that: suppose you are funded to work full-time in your research thesis-based Masters program. If you will be working on a second degree at the same time, it will inevitably drain your energy, so you'll likely be less productive to do what you are paid for.

Consult with the coordinators of your research Masters program to learn their stance on taking external education / work.

For a personal example, my university asks me to inform if I am receiving a funding from other sources and generally cuts the base funding depending on how much work time I spend on working for those other sources.

As a final note, you could take two Masters program covertly, without informing the two universities. They are unlikely to discover this, but it doesn't mean it's a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. You have highlighted all the main points that I want to know.